# how to correct an overflow problem related to the structure pointer?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct, valgrind

I did not share all of my code since it's long, so I hope you can help me with the debugging I did with valgrind and it's overflow problem.
I just wanted to retrieve data that I assigned in this pointed structure in another function.

```
struct paramAL{
    int noVersion;
    int noligne;
    char tligne[100];
    };
```

Here is the part of the readTrans function in which I assigned data to the pointed structure

```
void* readTrans(char* nomFichier){
        FILE *f;
        char buffer[100];
        char *tok, *sp;
        pthread_t tid[1000];
        int nbThread = 0;
        int i;
    
        //Ouverture du fichier en mode "r" (equiv. "rt") : [r]ead [t]ext
        f = fopen(nomFichier, "rt");
        if (f==NULL)
            error(2, "readTrans: Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier.");
    
        //Lecture (tentative) d'une ligne de texte
        fgets(buffer, 100, f);
        
        //Pour chacune des lignes lues
        while(!feof(f)){
    
            //Extraction du type de transaction 2 cas: commande avec arguments et sans argument
            tok = strtok_r(buffer, " .", &sp);
    
            //Branchement selon le type de transac  
            if(strcmp(tok, "AL") == 0){
                //Extraction des paramètres
                int noVersion = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &sp));
                int noligne = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &sp));
                char *tligne = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &sp);
                //Appel de la fonction associée
                struct paramAL *ptr = (struct paramAL*) malloc(sizeof(struct paramAL));
                ptr->noVersion = noVersion;
                ptr->noligne = noligne;
                strcpy(ptr->tligne,(const char *)tligne);
                pthread_create(&tid[nbThread++], NULL, addItemL,(void*) ptr);   
            } else if(strcmp(tok, "CV") == 0) {
                //Extraction des paramètres
                int noVersion = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, "\n ", &sp));
                //Appel de la fonction associée
                copyItemV(VRAI, noVersion); 
            }
    
            //Lecture (tentative) de la prochaine ligne de texte
            fgets(buffer, 100, f);
        }
        for(i=0; i<nbThread;i++)
            pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
        //Fermeture du fichier
        fclose(f);
        //Retour
        return NULL;
    }
```

This is the part of the code of concern:

```
void* addItemL(void* parama){  
    char tl[100]; 
    int noVersion, nl;
    
    struct paramAL *param = parama;
        
    noVersion = param->noVersion;
    nl = param->noligne;
    strcpy(tl,(const char*)param->tligne);
    free(param);
    struct noeudV * ptrV;
    
    ptrV = findItemV(noVersion);

    // Verifier si la version existe
    if (ptrV==NULL)
        return NULL;

    //Création de l'enregistrement en mémoire
    struct noeudL* ni = (struct noeudL*)malloc(sizeof(struct noeudL));

    struct noeudL* ptrINS = findItemL(noVersion, nl);

    //Affectation des valeurs des champs
    ni->ligne.noligne   = nl;
    strcpy(ni->ligne.ptrligne, tl);

    if((ptrINS == NULL) && (nl == 1)) // ajout au debut de la liste vide
    {
        // premiere ligne premier noeud 
        ni->suivant= NULL;
        ptrV->finL = ptrV-> debutL = ni;

    }
    else if ((ptrINS == NULL) && (nl > 1)) // ajout a la fin de la liste
    {
        struct noeudL* tptr = ptrV->finL;
        ni->suivant= NULL;
        ptrV->finL = ni;
        tptr->suivant = ni;
    }
    else
    {
        struct noeudL* tptr = ptrINS;
        if(tptr == ptrV->debutL) // ajout a la tete de la liste
            ptrV->debutL = ni;
        else
        {
            struct noeudL* ptrPREV = findPrevL(noVersion, nl);
            ptrPREV->suivant = ni;
        }
        ni->suivant = tptr;
        
        while (tptr!=NULL) {
            //Est-ce le prédécesseur de l'item recherché?
            tptr->ligne.noligne++;
            //On retourne un pointeur sur l'item précédent

            //Déplacement du pointeur de navigation
            tptr=tptr->suivant;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here are the errors detected by the valgrind :

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./gestionCVS_MAIN t2.txt                                                                                                                                                                            
==50153== Memcheck, a memory error detector                                                                                                                                                                                      
==50153== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.                                                                                                                                                        
==50153== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info                                                                                                                                                    
==50153== Command: ./gestionCVS_MAIN t2.txt                                                                                                                                                                                      
==50153==                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
noVersion  Nom Version                                  
======= ================================================
1        V1

2        

3        

4        

======= ===============================================

noVersion noligne       texte                                          
=======   ===========   ==================================
=========================================================

noVersion noligne       texte                                          
=======   ===========   ==================================
=========================================================

noVersion noligne       texte                                          
=======   ===========   ==================================
=========================================================

==50153== Invalid read of size 4
==50153==    at 0x400E04: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==  Address 0x576f150 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 108 free'd
==50153==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==50153==    by 0x400E44: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==
==50153== Invalid read of size 4
==50153==    at 0x400E13: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==  Address 0x576f154 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 108 free'd
==50153==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==50153==    by 0x400E44: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==
==50153== Invalid read of size 1
==50153==    at 0x4C2E1C7: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==50153==    by 0x400E35: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==  Address 0x576f158 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 108 free'd
==50153==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==50153==    by 0x400E44: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==
==50153== Invalid read of size 1
==50153==    at 0x4C2E1E4: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==50153==    by 0x400E35: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==  Address 0x576f159 is 9 bytes inside a block of size 108 free'd
==50153==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==50153==    by 0x400E44: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==
==50153== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==50153==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==50153==    by 0x400E44: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==  Address 0x576f150 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 108 free'd
==50153==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==50153==    by 0x400E44: addItemL (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x4012E4: copyItemV (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x402129: readTrans (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==    by 0x400BAE: main (in /home/mi136/Documents/testtp/test5/exempleCVS-A20/gestionCVS_MAIN)
==50153==
noVersion  Nom Version                                  
======= ================================================
1        V1

2        

3        

4        

======= ===============================================

noVersion noligne       texte                                          
=======   ===========   ==================================
=========================================================

noVersion noligne       texte                                          
=======   ===========   ==================================
=========================================================

-rw-r--r-- 1 mi136 www-data  89 sep 29 21:16 V1.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mi136 www-data  44 oct 25 17:22 V1?.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 mi136 www-data 108 sep 29 21:16 V2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mi136 www-data   0 oct 13 12:46 V2?.c

 Mon Premier Programme CVS

 Mon Premier programme CVS non pas le Dernier
==50153==
==50153== HEAP SUMMARY:
==50153==     in use at exit: 557,952 bytes in 4,104 blocks
==50153==   total heap usage: 8,215 allocs, 4,113 frees, 2,888,760 bytes allocated
==50153==
==50153== LEAK SUMMARY:
==50153==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==50153==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==50153==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==50153==    still reachable: 557,952 bytes in 4,104 blocks
==50153==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==50153== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==50153== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==50153==
==50153== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==50153== ERROR SUMMARY: 46 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You are accessing a freed block of memory.  It is memory freed by the one call to `free()` in the code you show.  It suggests that the calling code is not cognizant that once the `addItemL()` function is called, the data passed to it is no longer accessible.  Some of the problem, therefore, is in the code that calls `addItemL()`.  Without an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), there isn't much we can do to help you.

Comment: if(strcmp(tok, "AL") == 0){
    //Extraction des paramètres
    int noVersion = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &sp));
    int noligne = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, " ", &sp));
    char *tligne = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &sp);
    //Appel de la fonction associée
    struct paramAL *ptr = (struct paramAL*) malloc(sizeof(struct paramAL));
    ptr->noVersion = noVersion;
    ptr->noligne = noligne;
    strcpy(ptr->tligne,(const char *)tligne);
    pthread_create(&tid[nbThread++], NULL, addItemL,(void*) ptr);   
  }

Comment: Please edit the code into the question.  There is an edit 'link' at the bottom right of the question.

Comment: I did not do free in the function in which I assigned the data to the paramAL structure,

here is the part of the function in which I assigned the values to the variable

Comment: It looks as though you continue to use the memory passed to `addItemL()` after it has been freed by `addItemL()` — that's how I interpret the information from Valgrind.  I've not spent the time studying the code to see what's up, but I didn't notice a reference to `parama` or `param` after the `free()`, suggesting that it is the calling code passing the freed pointer again (without having accessed the data in the mean time, which is a bit surprising).  This is why we ask for an MCVE; it saves from having to speculate.

Comment: Yes I made a free because I assigned the values of the elements of the pointed structure to variables,

I put the code in which I assign the values to the pointed structures

Comment: "I did not share all of my code since it's long" That is fine, just make sure that what you provide is a [mre].

Comment: I modified the code to make it shorter and gave what you need to help me

Comment: Perhaps you have made the coed shorter, but it still is not a [mre].  In the first place, you could surely cut out rather a lot of the code in the functions you have presented without resolving the issue.  In the second, more important place, your Valgrind stack traces all include function `copyItemV()`, no version of which is presented.  As Jonathan remarked earlier, the problem is likely to be rooted in inconsistent behavior and expectations of *two* functions.  If so, then one of them surely is `addItemL()`, and the other is very likely `copyItemV()`.

Comment: Also, if you compile with debug information (and do not afterward strip it) then Valgrind should give you line numbers in the stack traces.  That will be a big help in tracking down the problem.